# regular expression for matching href relative path to current URL

Tags: regex, url, path, href

I'm creating a menu for a site that doesn't have any server-side capabilities. Because of this, my only way of highlighting the current page in the menu dynamically (among other changes) is to check the current URL and compare it against the path to the current file; when they match, I add a class of "current" as well as change the values of some other attributes.

The problem is that my regular expression only matches href values that are a single file name, not relative paths to other folders. For instance, if my menu is stored in the "category" folder, `href="page.html"` will match "http://www.example.com/category/page.html" but if I used `href="../category/page.html"` it wouldn't match. Same problem if I use a root relative path in the href.

My current regex is `/[^\/]+$/)[0]`. Here's what the whole script looks like:

```
$(document).ready( function () { 
  var pathname = (window.location.pathname.match(/[^\/]+$/)[0]); 
  var currA = $("#nav-sub li a[href='" + pathname + "']"); 
  var treeParent = currA.closest(".tree-parent"); 
  treeParent.attr('aria-expanded', 'true'); 
  currA.parents("li").addClass("current");
  treeParent.children('a').first().attr('tabindex','0'); 
});
```

Comment: do you know what `/[^\/]+$/` do?

Answer (score 0):

Your whole situation would be way easier to deal with if you just used root relative paths in all your menu hyperlinks.  Then you could just compare against window.location.pathname.

Assuming that is not possible you can use the [jq-uri](http://code.google.com/p/js-uri/) library to get root relative paths in javascript from whatever href you have.  It's basically a library wrapper around the regexs you are looking for.

To get the root relative path for a given href would be something like:

```
var href = "../test";

var base_uri = new URI(window.location.href); 
var uri = new URI(href);
uri.resolve(base_uri).path;
```

To get your desired functionality you could just:

1. Loop through all the menu anchor tags
2. Apply the above code against the HREF to get a root relative path
3. Compare the computed path against window.location.path
4. Apply your "current" class and other changes when you find a match.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can make root relative paths a requirement if that's easiest. What would the resulting script look like then? Just `var pathname = (window.location.pathname);` for that second line?

Comment: Yes, that will work if you use root relative paths for your links AND your link URIs do not contain a query string or hash.  "window.location.pathname" will not include the '?' or '#' from the URL or anything that comes after them.

For example, if the URI of the current page is "http://asdf.com/test1/test2?q=qwerty" then window.location.pathname should return "/test1/test2".